# Reading JSON File and Writing to csv

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to extract the below data from the json file and convert it in to csv file.  however when i try to read the json file I am getting error as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject"

**Required Fields**
1.AssessmentID
2.AssessmentName
3.AccountName
4.AssetName
5.ApplicationName
6.AccountType
7.environment

**JSON I recieve from application**
[
{
"assessmentID":154,
"assesmentName":"TestApp _50553_WEB_CLIENT_08-02-2021 17:02:22",
"assessmentAccounts":
[{"accountName":"a.pss.apitest","assetName":"TestApp01","applicationName":"TestApp","accountType":"scbdev.net","environment":"Test"},
{"accountName":"1562081","assetName":"TestApp02","applicationName":"TestApp05","accountType":"LocalAccount","environment":"Test"}]
},
{
"assessmentID":155,
"assesmentName":"TestApp _50553_WEB_CLIENT_08-02-2021 17:19:39",
"assessmentAccounts":
[
{"accountName":"a.pss.apitest","assetName":"TestApp","applicationName":"TestApp03","accountType":"scbdev.net","environment":"Test"},
{"accountName":"1562081","assetName":"TestApp","applicationName":"TestApp04","accountType":"LocalAccount","environment":"Test"}
]}
]

**MyCode:**
public static void main(String args[]) {

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\1451615\\genie-projects\\AppOnboarding\\src\\test\\resources\\features\\appdata.json"))
    {
        //Read JSON file
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray AppAssessmentData = (JSONArray) obj;
        System.out.println(AppAssessmentData);
        AppAssessmentData.forEach( account -> parseAccountObject((JSONObject) account) );
    }
 catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

```
private static void parseAccountObject(JSONObject account) {
//Get assessment accounts
    JSONObject Assessment_Account = (JSONObject) account.get("assessmentAccounts");

//Get accountname
    JSONObject account_Name = (JSONObject) account.get( "accountName" );

    //Get assetname
    JSONObject asset_Name = (JSONObject) account.get( "assetName" );

    //Get applicationname
    JSONObject application_name = (JSONObject) account.get( "applicationName" );

}
```

Comment: assessmentAccounts is an array, not a json object.  Anything between "[" and "]" in json is an array.  JSONObject Assessment_Account = (JSONObject) account.get("assessmentAccounts");

Comment: You can read json content easily with gson library. fetch the data and create an excel. See here to learn how to fetch json data from a file correctly http://techprogramme.com/2021/02/10/how-to-read-a-json-file-in-java/